# Relate $\sum{a_n}$ and $\sum{n a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\sum{a_n}=x$ and $\sum{n a_n}=y$ and both converge, is there any relation between $x$ and $y$?

Comment: No. e.g. consider the sequence $(a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots ) = (x-y,y,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: If the sums start at $n=1$ and the entries $a_n$ are nonnegative then $x\leqslant y$. Otherwise, see @achille's comment.

Comment: I asked because I noticed that $\zeta(3)=\sum{1/n^3}=$[Apéry's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apery%27s_constant) and $\zeta(2)=\sum{1/n^2}=\sum{n/n^3}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Given the answer here I asked [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/889001/820).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \lt 1$ then the function:
$$
f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n
$$
has a radius of convergence $\gt1$. consequently it is holomorphic on the unit disc. its derivative $\frac{df}{dz} = g(z)$ has the same radius of convergence as $f(z)$ and: 
$$
f(1) = x \\
g(1) = y
$$