# What's $\sum{\frac{x^n}{n^3}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, power-series

What's $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{x^n}{n^3}}$?

Note its derivative:

$$\displaystyle f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{x^{n-1}}{n^2}}$$

and the next derivative:

$$\displaystyle f''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty{\frac{x^{n-2}(n-1)}{n^2}}$$

I'm asking because $f(1)$ is [Apéry's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apery%27s_constant) $=\zeta(3)$, $$f'(1)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\zeta(2) \text{ and } f''(1)=\infty.$$

Comment: So, you know that $f(1)$ doesn't have a closed form, but you ask if $f(x)$ does?

Comment: Note that if you multiply by $x$ before the second derivative, then that derivative brings down $n$ again rather than $n-1$. That makes computations more straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the definition of a special function called [trilogarithm $\operatorname{Li}_3(x)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html). This is a special case of the polylogarithm
$$\operatorname{Li}_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k^n},$$
which has the properties $x\operatorname{Li}'_n(x)=\operatorname{Li}_{n-1}(x)$ and $\operatorname{Li}_n(1)=\zeta(n)$. These identities naturally generalize those mentioned in the question.